# Is it possible to use my own mp3s and Apple/iCloud Music Library simultaneously?

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-music

Ever since I've begun using Apple Music I feel as if I'm either only able to listen to my own music (mp3s synced to my iPhone) by having iCloud Music Library disabled, or listen to Apple Music by leaving it enabled (and not being able to access my own music). For example, if I sync all my music from iTunes to my phone and then go into Airplane Mode, the majority of it disappears.

Is there a way to have both my own mp3s and Apple Music at the same time? It seems absurd that you have to pick one or the other.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you found a solution for that ?

Comment: @Max No, I never did. Shortly afterwards I began using solely streaming and no mp3s so I stopped looking. Wouldn't be surprised if it remains this way.

Answer (score 1):

I've just discovered a Mac app, [WALTR 2](https://softorino.com/w2/), that I've used to successfully (and very easily) copy some mp3s to my iPhone over Wi-Fi, and they now appear in my iTunes library as local files, with all the correct metadata and album art. iCloud Music still enabled the whole time.

(I am in no way affiliated with WALTR 2, just was having the same problem as you and wanted to recommend an app that works for me.)

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use both at the same time, you you add your own music to your collection on your PC or Mac which Apple Music enabled both on the computer and phone then Sync your phone you will be able to see both your personal files and Apple Music.

Comment: I don't think this works, as described in my question. When I have Apple Music enabled and go into Airplane mode, lots of my music disappears, including artists/songs I own the mp3s of.

Comment: Just tried in case I missed something and can confirm that this does not work (as suspected). Follow these instructions and go into Airplane mode (or lose connection) and your mp3s will disappear.